# Как запретить анимацию togglebutton?

Tags: c#, wpf

Знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу запретить анимацию нажатия ToggleButton ?  Если кнопка нажата, то другая автоматически меняет стиль на не нажатую, но если я нажму на кнопку, которая нажата - она отжимается - как запретить этот "отжим" ?

Comment: Насколько я понял, нужно сделать, чтобы из двух `ToogleButton` активным мог быть только один?

Comment: Да, при этом если повторно нажать на активный то он не изменится, и так же останется активным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто обработать событие `Click` для каждого `ToogleButton`.

```
 <ToggleButton Name="toogle1" Click="Toogle1_OnClick"></ToggleButton>
 <ToggleButton Name="toogle2" Click="Toogle2_OnClick"></ToggleButton>
```

Обработчики :

```
    private void Toogle1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (ToggleButton)e.OriginalSource;
        if ((bool)button.IsChecked)
        {
            button.IsEnabled = false;
            toogle2.IsChecked = false;
            toogle2.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }


    private void Toogle2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (ToggleButton)e.OriginalSource;
        if ((bool)button.IsChecked)
        {
            button.IsEnabled = false;
            toogle1.IsChecked = false;
            toogle1.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Comment: @Елизавета, Пожалуйста!